# Share Point Security

Tags: share

I want to hide/no access to the main page of my companies SharePoint from the basic users. While giving full access to only some of the upper management.The goal is to have the basic users to have a limited access point to Share point But no access to the homepage.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easily accomplished with permissions.  Is there a specific part of site permissions that you have questions about?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Audience concept in webparts. This way, users will see blank home page without the content on specific webpart. 
Ref: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293

Another option is to break the permissions in pages or site pages library where your home page is stored. You can remove all users permissions except specific AD or SharePoint group which you want to assign permission.

In general, most users use Audience concept to maintain pages view for various users.

Answer (score 1):

Denying permissions to the top default resource is not the optimal way to go, as you'll have to deal with a lot of Access Denied, Not Shared With You, etc. support calls in your your helpdesk.

Better use the home page to display the information available to everyone, and lock down specific sections deeper down the hierarchy, create restricted subsites or even better site collections.

You can surface information from restricted areas to the right people in a security-trimmed fashion by means of including Content Search web parts and things like that on the home page. That way the URL will be the same for all, but the page contents will be different.

Comment: I want to give access to certain people to access the homepage. All my other user will not have access to the homepage. My users have a linked that they access that sits on the sharepoint page but thats it. I dont want them  having access to the homepage at all.

Comment: That's your choice to do as you wish, but it's my choice to warn you about possible consequences.